# Action bar does not show in tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-actionbar, android-tabhost

I have three tabs (A,B,C) and I want to add a **home** action bar on each tab. Not sure what I have missed here, no action bar is shown on each fragment. Below show the code of Fragment A.

**Fragment A**

```
  @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.tab_1_menu, menu);
        }

 @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.homePage:
                    Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),Edit.class);
                    startActivity(i);
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
          }
```

**tab_1_menu**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:icon="@mipmap/home"
        android:id="@+id/homePage"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Tab"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

**TabsFragmentAdapter**

```
public class TabsFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if(index == 0) {
            Fragment fragment = new A();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putLong("ID", Edit.ID);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return fragment;
        }

        if(index == 1) {
            Fragment fragment = new B();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putLong("ID", Edit.ID);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return fragment;
        }

        if(index == 2) {
            Fragment fragment = new C();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putLong("ID", Edit.ID);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return fragment;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 3;
    }
```

**Activity**

```
public class ActivityB extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private TabsFragmentPagerAdapter tabsAdapter;
    private String[] item = new String[]{"A","B","C"};
    private String id;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);
//        id=getIntent().getExtras().getString("ID");
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        tabsAdapter = new TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabsAdapter);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(item[i]).setTabListener(this));
        }
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add the `ActionBar` to your Activity that contains  `FragmentPagerAdapter` by add 2 functions

```
@Override 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present. 
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu. tab_1_menu, menu); 
return true; 
}

    @Override 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
switch (item.getItemId()) { 
case R.id.homePage: 
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Edit.class); 
startActivity(i); 
} 
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
}
```

Then in each `Fragment`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    ...
}
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.findItem(R.id.homePage).setVisible(false); // hide the action bar item
   menu.findItem(R.id.homePage).setIcon("Your Image"); // change actionbar item icon
    ...
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: i have modify my answer. please check it

Comment: Not really understand. Did you mean I have to add `homePage` into `if(index == 0)` ?

Comment: also, post your code in the activity (that contains your FragmentPagerAdapter). i will explain more in code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98756/discussion-between-phan-vn-linh-and-john).

Comment: can put all icon in `tab_1_menu` ?

Comment: ok you can do it, after that, in each frament, you can hide the icon, or change the image of icon